# comparisons of side lengths on a triangle

Tags: triangles

I am trying to find the relationship between the sides of any triangle as part of a bigger problem.

I was thinking about altering the Pythagorean theorem, but all I got was the useless $a^2+b^2\lesseqgtr c^2$ which is basically completely useless.
What I am after is something like $a^2+b^2\leq c^2$, which will actually mean something!!

Comment: What about the triangle inequality?

Comment: um @vitamind i kind of need an equality that tells me something about the sides, whilst $\lesseqgtr $ just tells me that $a^2+b^2$ and $c^2$ can be anywhere.

Comment: There is the inequality: $x+y\ge z$, don't know if it helps you.

Comment: is that for all triangles?

Comment: Yes but $z$ has to be the longest side. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: wow cool thats really useful thanks @vitamind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic triangle inequality states that
$$a+b\ge c$$
if $c$ is the biggest side. Triangle inequalities that are related to Pythagoras theorem are
$$a^2+b^2 < c^2, \quad\text{if angle $C$ is obtuse (greater than 90°)},$$
$$a^2+b^2 > c^2, \quad\text{if angle $C$ is acute (less than 90°)}.$$
In general we may write
$$a^2+b^2>\frac{c^2}{2}.$$
For more triangle inequalities, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_triangle_inequalities).